# Need a better solution than google analytics for data visualization dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, data-visualization, analytics, data-analysis, firebase-analytics

I trying to find a better solution than google analytics to create dashboards for visually representing custom data.

My use case is that I need something to track and record custom data that is not passed in through custom web events into google analytics. 
I was able to find a hacky solution to the problem initially by running a periodic function over my data on firebase and sending it as custom events to google-analytics. (*I mention the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64097298/11565176). The linked [blog post](https://nsr-py.github.io/blog/how-to-add-custom-KPI-tracking-in-Google-analytics) gives further details.*)

The problem that I faced was that it wasn't always reliable as although the function did run successfully every day, the data was not shown in the google analytics dashboard.
[image]

> The data I to visualize is gathered as further insights by writing basic code on existing data

**I am aware that it is possible to integrate google analytics for various use cases like even the smallest button click, but I am trying to either send custom events( raised outside of the application by running cron jobs or scheduled functions ) through some API call or maybe directly save and update the data in some other place where there is direct access to visualization**

Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol allows developers to make HTTP requests to send raw user interaction data directly to Google Analytics servers, so you can use it to send your data generate outside your application:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1